# Show that $\frac{z}{z+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm doing some  complex analysis work and I came upon this equivalency:

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{z+1} =  1 - \frac{1}{z+1}$$

I was trying to find out how to go from $z/ (z+1)$ to the equivalent expression but I'm having issues. I thought I could've used partial fractions but that doesn't appear to do the trick. I'm doing this in regards to prepping the function to use the corollary of Cauchy's theorem where $F' = f$ if $f$ is analytic on a domain.

Answer (score 2):

$$
A-\frac{B}{C}=\frac{AC-B}{C}
$$
and, in particular,
$$
1-\frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{z+1-1}{z+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{z}{z+1}=\dfrac{z+1-1}{z+1}=\dfrac{z+1}{z+1}-\dfrac{1}{z+1}=1-\dfrac{1}{z+1}$$

Comment: was just going to work it out and say synthetic division.  Thanks though.

Comment: actually, expanding on that, what woud possess the author to want to expand it into this form to solve the integral?

Comment: @dc3rd Knowing that that is the first step in a general algorithm that allows to integrate *all* rational functions. The first step is to divide to get a polynomial and a proper fraction.

Comment: @dc3rd This is the first step of tackling an integral of the form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with $p,q$ polynomials. The general procedure is called polynomial (long) division and the result will be $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = s(x) + \frac{r(x)}{q(x)}$ where $\deg r < \deg q$ so partial fraction decomposition is possible.